# How to make EclipseCDT source directories hierarchicaly?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I do have a project that has a lot of source diretories. Those are organized like this:

software_unit/src/library/ (*.h/*.cpp)

In order to develop it is needed to define each directory as source folder (50+ libs). What is displayed in eclipse project explorer is:

- su_a/src/lib_a/
- su_a/src/lib_b/
- su_b/src/lib_c/

(flat view)

What I want is:

- su_a/src/

  - lib_a
  - lib_b
- su_b/src/

  - lib_c

or alternative

- su_a

  - src

    - lib_a
    - lib_b
- su_b

  - src

    - lib_c

(hierarchical)

There is an option Projects Presentation -> Hierarchical, but that doesn't work this way.

Comment: There is no way to do that presently, [patches](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing), [bug reports](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) and funding welcome.

Comment: Sidenote: With so many libraries the Project explorer gets crowded with pathes. To get it somewhat cleaned up one can got to Preferences -> C/C++ -> Appearance -> uncheck "Show source roots at top of project". This is not what was requested in the question but it helps getting the project more clearly laid out.